# Cloud Composer DAG Scheduling based on Big Query Table

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, schedule, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

I am new to cloud composer and DAG. For one of our projects, we need to run the DAG monthly. But run date is different for each month and each year.
So, we are thinking of updating the run date in a big query table and then query that table inside DAG and schedule it based on the dates specified in the table. Is it possible?

I have tried to use a code which I got from google search. But it is not working.

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tsVU.png) 
I have tried to add code here.But it is saying formatting is wrong. So adding the image.

Comment: How changeable is "run date is different for each month and each year."? I'm asking this to check wether [timetables](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/scheduling-in-airflow#example-custom-timetable) satisfies your need.

Comment: Dates are decided by business every year. it depends on some third party requiremnt.so we cannot predict the dates much.